# Scroll view with dynamic spacing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a scrollable dialog box with text and buttons.  If the content of the dialog is taller than the scroll viewport, I want the content to all be aligned at the top of the viewport.  If all of the content is able to fit within the viewport without scrolling, I want it to be aligned in the center of the viewport.

[image: Img1]

*Img1 : example of how the content should be aligned vertically in the center if the content can fit within the scroll viewport.*

[image: Img2]

*Img2: example of how the content should be aligned vertically at the top if the content is too large to all fit within the scroll viewport.*

This is the structure of my canvas

```
Canvas
|
|---Scroll View (contains Scroll Rect component)
    |
    |---Viewport
    |    |
    |    |---Content (contains Vertical Layout Group, Content Size Fitter)                     
    |        |
    |        |---Text (contains Horizontal Layout Group component)
    |        |
    |        |---Button (contains Horizontal Layout Group component)
    |        |   |
    |        |   |---Text
    |        |
    |        |---Text (contains Horizontal Layout Group component)
    |     
    |---Scrollbar Vertical
```

I am trying to handle vertical positioning by dynamically calculating the padding in the `Vertical Layout Group` that is attached to the `Content` element.  When everything should be top-aligned, I set the padding to 10.  When everything should be center-aligned, I determine the height of each UI element and set the padding appropriately to cause everything to appear center.

The dialog's text is set by a `SetText` method which is part of the script that is attached to the canvas.  `SetText` assigns the text for each control in the dialog, and then does all the padding calculations.

The problem is that Unity doesn't seem to calculate each control's dimensions immediately after I assign text.  For example, if I set a breakpoint in my code after I assign text to one of the `Text` controls for the first time, all of the size-related properties are still 0.  Then when I assign a new text value, the size-related properties have their values from the first text value that I assigned.

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  I changed the pivot's y-value in the `Content` element from 1 to 0.5.  Now Unity centers when necessary and top-aligns when necessary without me having to figure out how to get that code to work.